# Where/when to check for user input with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following issue: let's say I have the following code, and I need to set some variables according which option is parsed to the program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Lorem ipsum")
    parser.add_argument('application', type=str, choices=['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'])
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--environment', type=str, default='prod', choices=['prod', 'dev'])
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

And I have to set variables `foo`, `bar`, `baz` according to the selected application, and `quz` according to the -e option.

Now my question is, where should I be making these checks? Inside the `if __main__ ...` statement? Inside my `main` function?

Also, since the the possible values are fixed (ie for aaa, `foo` will be 2342), what would be the proper way to do it? Write a dictionary for each application option with the possible values and read from there?

For example:

```
opt_aaa = {
    foo = 2342
    bar = 'some_str'
    baz = 5
}
```

Truth to be told, I just can hardcode the values and call the `main` function, but I much rather learn the pythonic and proper way to do it.

Any advice you may have will be truly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not really an answer but just my personal views:
For argument validation, always do it as soon you start you program and fail as soon as you find an invalid input. Basically, fail early and fast.  
For your second question - The proper way would be to create a config file and load the values from config file based on the option input. For example - you could create a different section in a config.ini file for each option and load that section using `configparser`

Comment: How come I didn't think of ConfigParser? I'm even already using it on this particular script. Great suggestion! I'm new to Python, about a month in, and it's great reading great comments and feedback! Thanks!